# std::unique_ptr use of deleted function с move

Tags: c++

Всем привет, есть следующий код:

```
struct RenderableAtmosphere {
    std::unique_ptr<Atmosphere> atmosphere;
    float hScaleFactor, parentEarthSizeCoefficient;
    bool isUseToneMapping = false;
};

struct RenderableSceneComponent {
...
    std::vector<RenderableAtmosphere> atmospheres;
};

...
RenderableSceneComponent uranusSystemComponent;

uranusSystemComponent.atmospheres = vector<RenderableAtmosphere>{move(renderableUranusAtmosphere)};
//uranusSystemComponent.atmospheres.push_back(move(renderableUranusAtmosphere));
```

В случае с вызовом оператора перемещающего присваивания код не компилируется со следующим набором ошибок:

```
In file included from D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/vector:62,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Auxiliary_Modules/Camera.h:5,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Auxiliary_Modules/AuxiliaryModules.h:4,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.h:3,
                 from D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.cpp:1:
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = RenderableAtmosphere; _Args = {const RenderableAtmosphere&}]':
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _ForwardIterator = RenderableAtmosphere*; _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1464:33:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_initialize(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = const RenderableAtmosphere*; _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere; _Alloc = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>]'
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:519:2:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Tp>, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = RenderableAtmosphere; _Alloc = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<RenderableAtmosphere>]'
D:\Clion\OpenGL_Projects\CourseWork_SolarSystem\src\Application.cpp:888:102:   required from here
D:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'RenderableAtmosphere::RenderableAtmosphere(const RenderableAtmosphere&)'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Я не могу понять, в какой момент вызывается копия класса, которая пытается вызвать удалённый конструктор копирования у `unique_ptr`. Но если использовать `push_back`, то всё работает

Comment: Почему закрываем? Пример вполне себе минимально-воспроизводимый. Написан конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @maestro, тоже не понял товарища, не совсем адекватный поступок, на мой взгляд..Не понравился набор ошибок ему, похоже..Много букав

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677660/stdunique-ptr-use-of-deleted-function-with-move?noredirect=1#comment121371069_68677660

Здесь ответили верно, фишка в [initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), в котором элементы хранятся как константы, и перемещение из него уже работать по этой причине не будет (из-за константности)